# Combine ieee-alphabetic with maxalphanames in biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style, author-number

I customized my bib labes to show the first three letters of the first author only and the full year, which requires `maxalphanames=1`. But I'd like to use the IEEE style for the actual bib entry.

**However, it is not possible to use `maxalphanames =` together with `style = ieee-alphabetic`**. Do you know any workaround?

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{reference.bib}
    @article{author1,
        author  = "George Orwell and Aldous Huxley and William Shakespeare and Oscar Wilde",
        title   = "1984",
        year    = "1948",
        journal = "Books about big brothers",
        volume  = "5",
        number  = "42",
        pages   = "100--111"
    }
\end{filecontents}


\RequirePackage[backend=biber,
                style=alphabetic,%
                % style=ieee-alphabetic, % does not work with maxalphanames
                maxnames=99,
                maxalphanames=1,  
                firstinits=true,
                defernumbers=true,
                ]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

% Label with full year
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field{year}    
  }
}

\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\begin{document}
    \cite{author1}. \\
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

So I'd like to combine this:

[image]

including the correct translation of **volume** and **number**, with this:

[image]

Comment: Note that the option `firstinits` has been renamed to `giveninits`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-ieee`'s `ieee-alphabetic` works perfectly well together with `maxalphanames`. It's just that it sets `maxalphanames = 4,` and `minalphanames = 3,`. Since we must always have `maxalphanames`>=`minalphanames`, we have to set

```
minalphanames=1, maxalphanames=1,
```

and things work.

---

But if it is only the format of `volume` and `number` that you want from `ieee-alphabetic`, you can have that with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace#1}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}%
}
```

in the standard style `alphabetic`.

Comment: I guess it's not just volume and number, it's more a "I don't want to think about which style rules to follow, but everybody in my field agrees with IEEE". Thanks for the addition anyway!